# CSS3 transition (hooked onto JS class change) not working in FF

Tags: firefox, css, transition

I have a CSS3 transition set to trigger on an h1 element, whenever some JavaScript changes the class name of a containing element to include "active". To do so I have two CSS declarations:

```
#idname .classname h1 {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -1.25em;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
```

Followed by:

```
#idname .classname.active h1 {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0; 
    -webkit-transition : all 4s ease;
    -moz-transition    : all 4s ease;
    -ms-transition     : all 4s ease;
    -o-transition      : all 4s ease;
    transition         : all 4s ease;
}
```

This works beautifully in webkit browsers, but appears to be failing in Firefox. My suspicion is this is something to do with how I'm triggering based on a class name change, though I could be wrong. Does Firefox not allow you to do this? Has anyone got a good workaround? Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: I just tried the above, and it seems to work fine in Firefox. Can you post a complete testcase that shows your issue?

Answer (score -1):

My problem was resolved by adding a slight delay between adding something to the DOM, and then adding a specific class name to trigger the animation. 20ms was long enough for me to get it working in Firefox.